# C++ std:string compilation error

Tags: c++

I have the following code in my cocos2d C++ application, but the code is not compiling:

```
  std::string MyBasketTimer::getImageByType(MyBasket* basket) {
        std::string retVal=NULL;
        if(getBasketType()==1){
            retVal= new std::string("count_bg.png");
        }
        else if(getBasketType()==2){
            retVal= new std::string("count_bg.png");
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

The error is get is

```
invalid conversion from 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to write Java or C#, but in C++. You should pick up a good beginner's book and start reading.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is a list of such books.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code would be correct if the return type of the function would be `std::string *`. For example

```
  std::string * MyBasketTimer::getImageByType(MyBasket* basket) {
        std::string *retVal=NULL;
        if(getBasketType()==1){
            retVal= new std::string("count_bg.png");
        }
        else if(getBasketType()==2){
            retVal= new std::string("count_bg.png");
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

However you declared the function such a way that it has return type `std::string`. So the valid function implementation will look the following way

```
  std::string MyBasketTimer::getImageByType(MyBasket* basket) {
        std::string retVal;
        if(getBasketType()==1){
            retVal.assign("count_bg.png");
        }
        else if(getBasketType()==2){
            retVal.assign("count_bg.png");
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: But the caller must delete the pointer in the first case

Comment: @Bathsheba And what is the problem?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the problem is that it is a fragile solution, and OP will use it and not delete it, then complain that C++ needs GC etc. etc. :-)

Comment: @ juanchopanza This has nothing common with the original post. He has some function declaration and need correctly to implement it.

Comment: -1 There's absolutely no reason to post the first half of your answer. It is obviously not the right solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: Typical Vlad posting dangerous and ill-advised pieces of code for no apparent reason.

Comment: +1 for posting a solution that helps the OP understand C++ even though it is ill-advised because the called has to call delete; and a contrasting method of doing the same thing.

Comment: @Rich I wrote in the post "Your code would be correct if... " I think all is clear. We did not discuss with the aothor of the question how to implement better some or other interface. The author got a full answer and his knowledge of C++ was enlarged. As for other trolls that mark down my posts then it is their aim to mark down my posta. It is not the first time. They think that they are very clever.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes my intention in my comment was to indicate that I agree with you. I wanted to explicitly say I was giving an up-vote and why because so many are being overly critical of the solution you provided. Clearly OP misunderstands some C++ concepts, and not necessarily design principal. Your answer addresses the issue at hand well.

Answer (score 4):

Your return type is `std::string` but you are trying to assign a pointer to `std::string` to it:

```
retVal= new std::string("count_bg.png");
```

You need to assign an `std::string` to `retVal`:

```
retVal = std::string("count_bg.png");
```

or use the implicit conversion from string literal:

```
retVal = "count_bg.png";
```

Furthermore, this

```
std::string retVal=NULL;
```

will most likely cause a runtime error: you cannot instantiate a string with a null pointer. This will call the `std::string` constructor that takes a `const char*`, and that is assumed to point to a null-terminated string.

Comment: Of course, this answer is so hideously wrong that it deserves the down-vote :-)

Answer (score 3):

The assignment `std::string retVal = NULL;` is invalid. Just default construct it using `std::string retVal;`

Also drop the `new` keywords as they create objects on the heap and return pointers to them. You need, for example, `retVal = std::string("count_bg.png");` (This is one important difference between C++ and Java).

Comment: +1 but it may be worth pointing out that `std::string retVal = NULL;` would compile, but would fail at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ (unlike some other languages) you don't need to allocate all class variables with `new`. Just assign it.

`retVal= "count_bg.png";`

Answer (score 3):

`std::string retVal` isn't a pointer. You can't initialize it with `NULL` (which should rather be `nullptr`...), nor assign the result of a memory allocation through `new`.

Just don't initialize it and assign directly the string then.

```
std::string retVal;
//...
retVal = "count_bg.png"
//...
return retVal;
```